# Disabling Windows Defender prevents from mounting ISOs

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, iso-image, windows-defender

After some consideration I [disabled Windows Defender in Windows 10 by using the registry](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-permanently-disable-windows-defender-windows-10). I browsed to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender` and created a new "DWORD (32-bit)" value titled `DisableAntiSpyware` with "value data" `1` (hexadecimal) Since then there has been a delay lasting several minutes when attempting to mount an ISO file, resulting in this error:

[image: error screenshot]

Both Windows Explorer and [WinCDEmu](http://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/) are unable to mount. 7-Zip can extract ISOs, but this process essentially duplicates files and takes a long time.

---

I'm well aware that disabling antivirus software isn't recommended on Windows, but I eventually found this as mandatory — I have to use "unofficial patches" to disable DRM (mainly SafeDisc and StarForce) in PC games only released on disc in order to run these games in the first place (discontinued activation servers) or on modern operating systems; Windows Defender kept deleting executable files.

Comment: So undo the deactivation of Windows Defender and see if it works again. My guess is that the problem lies elsewhere. // Windows Defender can be set to exclude certain files. I suggest you use that instead.

Comment: @DanielB: Enabling Windows Defender resolves the issue, sorry for not mentioning explicitly. I'll see later if I can completely exclude folders, but I still want to know how this issue is caused.

Comment: This may not be an issue anymore.